# Is constantly questioning yourself a virtue or a drawback?

Tags: skepticism, doubt

In modern society, skepticism in things is taken to be a virtue. Presumably, this is equated with being open minded and having an easier willingness to change your mind in the wake of new evidence.

On the other hand, skepticism, doubt, and the notion of uncertainty can often result in poor psychological well-being. Self doubt, religious uncertainty, and uncertainty of what happens after death, predict a higher chance of [depressive symptoms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6801496/).

Secondly, why would certainty in a belief imply you can’t change your mind about a topic? As an example, I presume most people do not believe in a flat earth. I would argue that most, atleast subjectively, feel certain of it. If tomorrow, concrete evidence came out in regards to a conspiracy by governments to promote a spherical earth, along with images of a flat earth, along with you taking a trip to space and seeing this flat earth, would you not change your mind? Would not most of the world?

If so, this would be an example of feeling certain of X without impacting your ability to change your mind if evidence of X’s falsehood came about.

Given this, is being continually skeptical a virtue or a drawback?

Comment: Rawls in *A Theory of Justice* speaks of the efficiency of deliberation in this connection: "... the value of the activity of deciding is itself subject to rational appraisal" (sec. 64), and he mentions elsewhere that for the utilitarian, even the choice of standards for utility appraisals can itself be subject to the question of evaluation (I don't recall which sec. exactly).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the subject, justification, impact and relevance of the doubt. If you are paralysed with indecision about the truth of a fact for which there is overwhelming evidence, and which, even if it were false might not make a big difference to your life- such as the question of whether the Earth was round- then your doubts would be dysfunctional.

Where skepticism is healthy is in relation to beliefs for which there is no clear evidence, or which are complex and require many different facets to be examined and weighed. Retaining an open mind in relation to such subjects can be better than adopting a firmly held view with too little reflection and research.

Answer (score 0):

> Scepticism in general, is not disbelief but suspension of belief, i.e.
> maintaining a neutral attitude that neither affirms nor denies the
> claim.

The word comes from the word "σκέφτομαι" +"ισμός" ( sceptomai+ismos ) which means: *the process of thinking*.

The opposite of skepticism is dogmatism.

> Some definitions, often inspired by ancient philosophy, see skepticism
> not just as an attitude but as a way of life. This is based on the
> idea that maintaining the skeptical attitude of doubt toward most
> concerns in life is superior to living in dogmatic certainty.

On the other hand the process of "constantly questioning yourself", is identified with the word "αμφιβάλλω", "αμφισβητώ" which means *my unwillingness to accept or to adopt something*.

So from this etymological analysis - which in fact is just the translation of the words - it seems that the answer is : *keep thinking about things, but do not necessary have an
unwillingness to accept or to adopt something*.

So, besides the fact that the word scepticism can have many connotations, it all depends on how you incorporate the concept into your way of life.